# Koahan ORM: Adding extra data to many-to-many relationships

Tags: php, kohana

I have my models setup as a many-to-many using `through` with a pivot table. However, I would like to add some extra data into the pivot table.

In the past (`kohana 3.0`) I was able to provide extra data with the add method

```
$obj->add('alias', $related, array('extra'=>'data'))
```

But its seems in Kohana 3.3 that the `add` method does not provide the third parameter for extra data, and I cannot seem to find how to do this short of after saving, adding more data then re-saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported anymore since `Kohana 3.1`.

The reason they removed it (Source: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3754):

> We decided to remove this because it's better to use a through model
>   if you need to put data in your pivot table. Inserting the data
>   directly in the add() method bypasses validation and filtering that
>   would normally be in your model. Use a model if you need data in your
>   through table. We won't be changing this.

You now have to make a model for the pivot table and place the additional information in that model.

Then instead of using `has_many "through" (n:n)` you should use `has_many (1:n)` relationship for both tables to the pivot table.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Great thanks for the info, makes sense! I have setup a n:n relationship, but also a 1:n on the same set of models, seems to be working fine...